# Sorting places my data with empty cells above it

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I have written a bunch of VBA macros to get my data formatted how I need it, and the last step is to sort by this new column I have generated in ascending order. However, when I hit sort by the new column, the code now places all the empty cells above my newly generated column as I think it is reading the empty as a 0 and sorts it above any alphanumeric data. This is happening because of the UDF I have for sorting the data. I need to insert the new column with the UDF for each new cell that I insert, but I don't know how to define the range in the new column. 
I am close to solving this but would love some help.

Essentially what I have tried for placing the data in a new column works, but the way I have set the range is placing it in a bad spot and it can easily be sorted in the wrong order now. I include all of my code, but the issue is in the last portion of it where I am setting a range to place the new data.

I think what is happening is when I set my range from C3-C2000 and populate it, the remaining empty cells are now included in my sort and give me "lower" numbers when I sort it ascending. Thus all the empty cells are ranked higher up in the column.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ContractilityData()
    Dim varMyItem As Variant
    Dim lngMyOffset As Long, _
        lngStartRow As Long, _
        lngEndRow As Long
    Dim strMyCol As String
    Dim rngCell As Range

    Columns("B:B").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove 'make new column for the data to go


    lngStartRow = 3 'Starting row number for the data. Change to suit
    strMyCol = "A" 'Column containing the data. Change to suit.

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For Each rngCell In Range(strMyCol & lngStartRow & ":" & strMyCol & Cells(Rows.Count, strMyCol).End(xlUp).Row)

        lngMyOffset = 0

        For Each varMyItem In Split(rngCell.Value, "_") 'put delimiter you want in ""
            If lngMyOffset = 2 Then 'Picks which chunk you want printed out (each chunk is set by a _ currently)
                rngCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = varMyItem
            End If
            lngMyOffset = lngMyOffset + 1
        Next varMyItem

    Next rngCell

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

 'Here is where my problem arises   
    Range("C:C").EntireColumn.Insert
    Dim sel As Range
    Set sel = Range("C3:C2000")
    sel.Formula = "=PadNums(B3,3)"



    MsgBox "Data Cleaned"

End Sub
```

What I would like instead is a way to insert a new column, then have my UDF "PadNums" populate each cell up to the last cell of the previous column, essentially re-naming all my data from the previous column. I can then sort by the new column in ascending order and my data is in the correct order.

I think perhaps what I should do is copy column B into my newly inserted column C, then use some sort of last row function to apply the formula in all cells. That would give me the appropriate range always based on my original column?

Comment: I solved this! What I did was use range and xlDown to last row on column B, then pasted it to C, then inserted my UDF into C using the xlDown range!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this! What I did was use range and xlDown to last row on column B, then pasted it to C, then inserted my UDF into C using the xlDown range!